# Demo public website in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am newbie to SharePoint Dev.I need to know how sharepoint dev approach towards a solution like menu drop down which shows list of categories like category 1, category 2 etc and by click on each category in menu. it display list of products. Categories main page should display slideshow of categories.

What is best way to apprach this senarios in sharepoint. how many list, webpart I have to develop? More option will be appreaciated.

How to decide which list, web part and work flow is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 lists, 1 lookup field and a webpart showing the two items. No workflow required.